# List comprehension with multiple variables

Tags: python

Is there any way to dequeue two or more items in list comprehension.

I.e. I'd like to do something like this:

```
>>> q = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> r = [x+y for x, y in q]
** This does not work though :( **
```

Expected:

```
>>> r
[3, 7]
```

Comment: expected solution for odd length list? for eg, `q=[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: odd length list -> some kind of error ... not too fussed as long as it is something vaguely sane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the grouper [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) documentation:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [x + y for x, y in grouper(2,q)]
[3, 7]
```

The source code for the recipe is this:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: Very nice generic solution :)

Comment: For work with smth like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you may use `[x + y for x, y in grouper(2,q,0)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Works if list only contains groups of 2 eg. wont work for `[1,2,3,4,5]` but will work for `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

```
>>> q = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(*[iter(q)]*2)]
[3, 7]
```

also as suggested by @gnibbler

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*[iter(q)]*2))
```

Comment: May be you can try `izip_longest` with `fill_value=0`? `>[sum(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(q)]*2,fillvalue=0)]`

Comment: I could have done it but @MarkByers already submitted that solution. This solution is better if you already know that data is in groups of 2.

Comment: also `map(sum, zip(*[iter(q)]*2))`

Comment: I will add that in as well :D

Comment: Neat but less general solution - really wishing I could award two answers. :)

Comment: Depends on your use case, I would also pick the `itertools` solution since `itertools` is always good to use :D

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
>>> [sum(q[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(q),2)]
[3, 7]
>>> q=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [sum(q[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(q),2)]
[3, 7, 5]
```

Comment: +1 Yeah! Indeed `sum` was a better way to do this, time to delete my solution.

Comment: Nice solution of the specific problem :) However I was looking for something generic.